# JetBrains Rider - how to execute a C# scratch

Tags: jetbrains-rider

In JetBrains Rider, when I create a scratch C# file, how can I execute it?
Making the Main method public static and adding a namespace seems to be not enough.

[image: Unable to find static method: MyNamespace.Foo.Main]

```cs
using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Rider version: JetBrains Rider 2022.3.1

Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a namespace is actually not even required. What worked for me is the following:

- creating a scratch file with the following content (as you already did):

```cs
using System;

class Foo
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
```

- then selecting the code you want to run/execute (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for the entire script)
- hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to bring up a tooltip menu and select "Send Selection to C# Interactive"
  [image: the tooltip menu can be seen in this image]
- this will open a C# interactive tab where you can input C# code such as `var x = new Foo();` (and it doesn't matter if Rider does not recognise `Foo()` as a valid constructor),
  [image: as can be seen in this image]
- lastly calling `x.Main()` will then run your function
  [image: another image with the result when calling the function]

You can also find a good description on this page: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/12/01/c-interactive-rider/

I hope this helped!

Comment: FYI: At the time of writing this comment, it is unfortunately not possible to use NuGet packages inside a scratch file... [This is the feature-request with state "Upvoting" as of writing this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-21806/Scratch-C-file-add-possibility-to-reference-project-assembly)